# Whats wrong if i do this?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
#web {

position:absolute;
left:26%;
top: 60%;
```

HTML

```
<div class="web">
HI
</div>
```

I don't know what's going wrong.  Can you modify and tell me whats wrong? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mzJV9/

The formatting doesn't effect the text inside..

The  position is still the same ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change #web to .web

or

change class="web" to id="web".

Comment: Also add closing } in css. I checked on jsfiddle and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/B54Kj/

Answer (score 0):

And, if it is not just a miss while copypasting the code, you've missed the closing bracket in style.

All together, it should be like this:

CSS:

```
.web {
position:absolute;
left:26%;
top: 60%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="web">
HI
</div>
```

It is also a good point not to use id's for styling whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, there's a difference between Ids and class selectors.

```
<div id="div1" class="mydivclass">
  My content!
</div>
```

Your styling can be done various ways:

```
/* Set CSS based on a class (prefix . to the class name) */
.mydivclass {
  /* */
}

/* Set CSS based on the ID (prefix # to the ID) */
#div1 {
  /*  */
}

/* Set CSS based on the element type - no prefix */
div {

}
```

If your case you can solve the issue by changing your CSS selector to `.web` (to access the class of your div) or by changing your div ID to `web`. Also, make sure all your CSS styles have closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Add the closing `}` in you css formatting and change this

```
<div class="web">
HI
</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="web">
HI
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate some of the other answers here...

A `.` prefix to your CSS selector is a `class` and a `#` prefix denotes an `id`. So, for example:

CSS:

`.myClass{/*some style information here*/}`

HTML:

`<div class="myClass"><!-- Some content here --></div>`

Is correct. As is:

CSS:

`#myID{/*some style information here*/}`

HTML:

`<div id="myID"><!-- Some content here --></div>`

And to follow on from unclenorton's comment about the us of `class` and `id`: I don't know if it is a strict standards requirement, but I've always done this and been given the same advice by several people:

Use `id`s for `div`s that are only used once - for example, layout divs that give the different 'sections' of your page. And use `class`es for repeating `div`s, for example a `sidebarItem` `div`.

Either way, be sure that you are consistent in your code - will make your life a whole lot easier; especially if you can maintain that consistency between projects as well, as it will become second-nature to you.